# Joining arrays on internal(nested ) row ids

Tags: google-bigquery

how can I join/sum up array values row by row (i.e. rows representing offset in the array) when joining two tables

i.e. given below two tables
the output for `row_id = 1` should be `STRUCT("A",ARRAY[41,43,45])` i.e. array of sum of `col1.val1` and `col2.val2` values for each `internal_id` corresponding to index in each array

```
WITH table1 AS (
  SELECT 1 AS row_id, STRUCT("A" AS internal_id, ARRAY[1,2,3] as val1) AS col1  
),
table2 AS (
    SELECT 1 AS row_id, STRUCT("A" AS internal_id, ARRAY[40,41,42] as val2) AS col2  
)
```

EDIT:
So I tried to do the below, un-nesting the arrays first, but the result is incorrect, i.e. it puts the resulting array at each index, i.e. having 9 rows instead of just 3

[image: result]

```
WITH table1 AS (
  SELECT 1 AS row_id, STRUCT("A" AS internal_id, ARRAY[1,2,3] as val1) AS col1  
),
table2 AS (
    SELECT 1 AS row_id, STRUCT("A" AS internal_id, ARRAY[40,41,42] as val2) AS col2  
),
table1_unnested as(
    select row_id, col1.internal_id, val1 from table1, unnest(col1.val1) as val1
),
table2_unnested as(
    select row_id, col2.internal_id, val2 from table2, unnest(col2.val2) as val2
)
select t1.row_id, t1.internal_id, ARRAY_AGG(t1.val1+t2.val2) as newval 
from table1_unnested as t1
join table2_unnested  as t2 using(row_id)
group by t1.row_id, t1.internal_id
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were very close - see below correction

```
WITH table1 AS (
  SELECT 1 AS row_id, STRUCT("A" AS internal_id, ARRAY[1,2,3] as val1) AS col1  
),
table2 AS (
    SELECT 1 AS row_id, STRUCT("A" AS internal_id, ARRAY[40,41,42] as val2) AS col2  
),
table1_unnested as(
    select row_id, col1.internal_id, val1, offset from table1, unnest(col1.val1) as val1 with offset
),
table2_unnested as(
    select row_id, col2.internal_id, val2, offset from table2, unnest(col2.val2) as val2 with offset
)
select t1.row_id, t1.internal_id, ARRAY_AGG(t1.val1+t2.val2) as newval 
from table1_unnested as t1
join table2_unnested  as t2 using(row_id, offset)
group by t1.row_id, t1.internal_id
```

with output

[image]

As you can see - I added `offset` in five(5) places to fix your original query